# Hazard of load address in mips

Tags: assembly, mips

Basically i have some mips instructions following these orders

```
array: .word 10, 20, 30, 10,20, 30

  la $t0, array
  lw $t1, 0($t0)
  lw $t2, 4($t0)
  add $t1, $t2, $t1
  lw $t2, 8($t0)
  bne $t1, $t2, label
  sw $t2, 16($t0)

label:
```

For the first two instructions, i dont know if the "load address" might cause hazards for the next "load word" instruction, does $t0 from lw need the value of $t0 from la? do we need to stall at which stage? I have searched many sources but not found any articles that wrote about *hazard of load address*.

Comment: Load address (`la`) is not a real instruction. It's a pseudo-instruction, often encoded something like this: `lui $reg, 16-bit-immediate; ori $reg, 16-bit-immediate`.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong:
1.) there's not going to be a IF-MEM stall, because of separate data and instruction memory. 
2.) `ori` will have to stall before ALU until WB of `lui`
3.) the `lw` after `la` will have to stall before ALU until WB of `ori` finishes.

Comment: @user35443  sorry forgot to mention that the forwarding method is allowed...

Comment: That could mean there would be no stall at all, but I'd rather wait for someone to confirm it.

Comment: i think there should be a load-use hazard between la and lw, doesnt lw need value of $t0 for the EX stage, after MEM stage of la finished (using forwarding)  like   la : IF  ID  EX  MEM  WB then lw: IF  x  ID EX  MEM  WB where x is the bubble (should stall one cycle)? So confusing.

Comment: The question is whether `lui` or `ori` affect `$t0` during MEM. I wouldn't say so, because both `lui` and `ori` are performed in ALU (EX), aren't they?

Comment: @user35443 so la includes 2 sub-instructions lui and ori  , which are --- lui $1, 4097 ---and --- ori $8, $1, 0 --- respectively (based on my MIPs program), 1st instruction,  the value of at($1) will be 4097 << 16 bits = 268500992,  and 2nd instruction the value of $t0 ($8) is also 268500992. To be honest, i dont know much about *lui*, you said the result of this inst is known at after EX stage right, not MEM stage?

Comment: @EOF thank you , but do we have any hazards in these sub-instructions (lui and ori) ?

Comment: Yeee, slow down. First of all, `lui` seems to be working just with registers, not memory. Therefore we can say, that the value supposed to be written into `$t1` won't change since EX stage. `lui` will load an intermediate, and righ after, `$t0` will get latched for `ori`, which means there will be no hazard.

Comment: okay i think i got this, but do we need to divide la into sub-instructions in the pipeline, each includes 5 stages? Just like other instructions?

Answer (score 0):

**la** is pseudoinstruction which can be rewrite as real MIPS instruction.

```
la $t0, array
lw $t1, 0($t0)
```

as an example you can write the `la` as following

```
lui $t0,%hi_array
ori $t0,$t0,%lo_array
lw $t1, 0($t0)
```

Of course it has **data hazard** as following

```
1  2  3   4   5   6   7

IF ID EXE MEM WB
   IF ID  EXE MEM WB
      IF  ID  EXE MEM WB
```

The `ori` instruction need to read `$t0` in third clock cycle but the value is not available until `lui` instruction writes it in fifth clock cycle which is WB and it's a  **data hazard**.
The same problem occur for the `lw` .